# Ansible community parted module asking "Are you sure you want to continue", is there an override

Tags: ansible, alpine-linux, xen

I am trying to expand an `ext4` partition to fill a disk on Alpine using Ansible.

Following the community parted module documentation [here](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/general/parted_module.html) I should be able too. However when it comes to performing that action the returned error message says `"Warning: Partition /dev/xvda3 is being used. Are you sure you want to continue?\n"`.

Is there anyway to force this action to proceed on a live system as it looks like Parted is asking for user interaction even though the `-s` flag is enable?

The task I'm using:

```yaml
 - name: Read device information
  community.general.parted: device=/dev/xvda unit=MiB
  register: sdb_info

 - name: Extend an existing partition to fill all available space
  community.general.parted:
    device: /dev/xvda
    number: "{{ sdb_info.partitions | length }}"
    part_end: "100%"
    resize: true
    state: present
```

The full error from `ansible-playbook main.yaml -vvvv`:

```yaml
fatal: [10.10.30.100]: FAILED! => {
    "changed": false,
    "err": "Warning: Partition /dev/xvda3 is being used. Are you sure you want to continue?\n",
    "invocation": {
        "module_args": {
            "align": "optimal",
            "device": "/dev/xvda",
            "flags": null,
            "fs_type": null,
            "label": "msdos",
            "name": null,
            "number": 3,
            "part_end": "100%",
            "part_start": "0%",
            "part_type": "primary",
            "resize": true,
            "state": "present",
            "unit": "KiB"
        }
    },
    "msg": "Error while running parted script: /usr/sbin/parted -s -m -a optimal /dev/xvda -- resizepart 3 100%",
    "out": "",
    "rc": 1
}
```

Target host:

- Alpine-VM 3.16.2
- Parted 3.5
- Python 3.10.5

Local:

- Ansible 2.13.3
- Python 3.10.4

Comment: Did you try to unmount the disk before running the playbook?

Answer (score 0):

According the documentation [community.general](https://galaxy.ansible.com/community/general) and source code [`community.general/blob/main/plugins/modules/system/parted.py`](https://github.com/ansible-collections/community.general/blob/main/plugins/modules/system/parted.py), the module is just a wrapper around the Linux tool `parted`.

Looking into other similar reports like Ubuntu Launchpad #[1270203](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/parted/+bug/1270203), the confirmation question

```
Warning: Partition <part> is being used. Are you sure you want to continue?
```

seems to be the normal and expected behavior if one tries to `resizepart` on a mounted partition.

> *Ansible community parted module asking "Are you sure you want to continue"*

So it is not community module which is asking, but the Linux tool `parted` itself.

> *is there an override*

In the community module itself is currently neither this corner case covered, nor an override implemented yet. Therefore the error message is thrown.

You could

- either try to unmount the partition before and mount after resize again with [`mount` module – Control active and configured mount points](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/posix/mount_module.html)
- or use the `shell` module with `cmd: /usr/sbin/parted -s -m -a optimal /dev/xvda -- resizepart 3 yes 100%` (... or `yes | ...`) as mentioned in the thread #[1270203](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/parted/+bug/1270203)
- or enhance the behavior of the module by patching and extending the source [`parted.py`](https://github.com/ansible-collections/community.general/blob/main/plugins/modules/system/parted.py) accordingly